# cohomology of projective space over non-noetherian ring

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology

The cohomology of projective spaces over a noetherian ring $A$ is computed in e.g. Hartshorne Chapter III.5. In particular, we know that $H^i(\mathbb{P}_A^n,\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}})$ are finitely generated $A$-modules.

How about these over non-noetherian rings? Do we still have the results analogous to the noetherian cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the same result holds via the same Cech cohomology computation. See [Stacks 01XT](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01XT) or EGA III proposition 2.1.12 for a full proof.

The key difference between Hartshorne's approach and that of Stacks/EGA is actually the claim that $H^p(X,\mathcal{F})=0$ for $X$ an affine scheme, $\mathcal{F}$ a quasi-coherent sheaf, and $p>0$. If we knew this, we'd have the desired result by Hartshorne exercise III.4.11 which shows that Cech cohomology is derived functor cohomology on a covering where the higher cohomology of the intersections vanishes (this is a baby case of the Cech-to-derived spectral sequence). Hartshorne only proves the claim that $H^p(X,\mathcal{F})=0$ for $X$ noetherian, but it is true in general (see [Stacks 01XB](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01XB) for the precise proof.)